# <Style> doesn't work fully when declared as an external stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html file and an external .css file. Inside the .html i have a table declared and in the .css file the following:

```
<style>


table,th,td {

   border: 3px solid black;
}

h1 {
   background-color: red;
}


</style>
```

When placed inside the .html file, works fine - table gets border, h1 gets color. When the code gets placed outside, a.k.a inside the external .css, only the h1 gets styled, the table not. Any ideas what may provoke it? Linking to external .css is declared correctly.

Comment: can you add the code of the html ? I want to see how you used external css file

Comment: If you file is an external `.css` file, you don't need `<style>` tags at all.

Comment: Please provide the full code, and also consider hitting ctrl+f5 when you refresh your page to update it or clear your cache. Hopefully its just a caching issue.

Comment: What exactly does your external .css file look like, also, how do you include the external css on your html page?

Comment: The declaration inside the html was <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web_test.css">. I removed the <style> tag from the external file and worked fine. Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: You don't write `<style>` tag inside .css file, same way you don't write `<script>` tag inside .js file. Browser is smart enough to know that .css file contains style and .js file contains javascript

Answer (score 0):

You haven't linked the external css file to HTML.

**And Moreover You don't need to use style tag in external CSS file.**

To Link External CSS file

Use code below in the head tag of HTML and place it there specifying your file in href attrbute

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='abc.css'>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment, i have linked the .css file correctly in my html.

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect your table code with browser, and see what styles are used there.